# WPF controls in Winforms do not update access keys/mnemonic underlines

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms-interop

I have a Winform with a menu strip that hosts a WPF control that has some buttons.  The `toolStripMenuItems` and the WPF buttons all have access keys set up.

When I hit "Alt", the letters for all the access keys become underlined as expected. When I hit the "Alt" key a second time the lines disappear on the `toolstripMenuItems` but not on the WPF buttons. The access keys still work.

It appears that the UI is not keeping up with the keystrokes. Is this by design? And how do I get uniform behavior across all controls in my app?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6abw.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTg4G.png]